# Why X265 conversion is very slow on some devices

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion, compression

When I am converting my video using FFMpeg, I am using x265 to do the compression. But the issue is this conversion is much much slower. But while I am using my iPad 6th Generation, this works much faster. So I want to know the reason behind this.

Note : X264 is working fine on both devices.

Thank you.

Comment: iPad is probably using Apple's h/w H265 encoder, not x265.

Comment: @Gyan no , im using the command to use x265

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.

The issue was ffmpeg was only using two thread and two pools. I had to trigger the parameter "-x265-params" to enable more thread and pools as my device capability.